# dropDuplicates in SparkR

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

Does SparkR contains [dropDuplicates](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) function (to drop duplicate rows based on a specific column) which is present in scala?

I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30257726/4057655) in SOF . But instead of using GroupBy, do we have a function to dropDuplicates in SparkR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do it by all columns, it's [distinct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/R/distinct.html)

```
distinct(x)
```

or

```
unique(x)
```

To do it "based on a specific column", as you said, your best bet is GroupBy, as spark cannot decide which one of your 'not distinct' records to keep.

Comment: But this does not support us to specify the column to identify duplicates

Comment: It seems there is not other function to do that. If you know of one such please update the answer

Comment: I think groupBy is the one. Note that you will have to provide an aggregation function for each column. you can define your own or you can use inbuilt functions like max.  e.g.  
df.groupBy("key_col").agg(max("col1"), max("col2"))