# Using dropDuplicates in dataframe causes changes in the partition number

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I have a large dataframe which I created with 800 partitions.

```py
df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
800
```

When I use dropDuplicates on the dataframe, it changes the partitions to default 200

```py
df = df.dropDuplicates()
df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
200
```

This behaviour causes problem for me, as it will lead to out of memory.

Do you have any suggestion on fixing this problem? I tried setting   spark.sql.shuffle.partition to 800 but it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates from rows based on specific columns in an RDD/Spark DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248221/removing-duplicates-from-rows-based-on-specific-columns-in-an-rdd-spark-datafram)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because `dropDuplicates` requires a shuffle. If you want to get a specific number of partitions you should set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` (its default value is 200)

```py
df = sc.parallelize([("a", 1)]).toDF()
df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
## 8

df.dropDuplicates().rdd.getNumPartitions()
## 200

sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "800")

df.dropDuplicates().rdd.getNumPartitions()
## 800
```

An alternative approach (Spark 1.6+) is to repartition first:

```py
df.repartition(801, *df.columns).dropDuplicates().rdd.getNumPartitions()
## 801
```

It is slightly more flexible but less efficient because doesn't perform local aggregation.

Comment: Thank you. I realised my mistake is in missing the last character 's' in spark.sql.shuffle.partition.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at [Removing duplicates from rows based on specific columns in an RDD/Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248221/removing-duplicates-from-rows-based-on-specific-columns-in-an-rdd-spark-datafram)

Use reduceByKey instead of dropDuplicates. reduceByKey also have an option of specifying the number of partitions for the final rdd.

The downside of using reduceByKey in this case is it is slow.