# Spark - drop duplicates inside a json array field

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataframe, duplicates, to-json

I share the code that I have:

```
// define a case class
case class Zone(id: Int, team: String, members: Int ,name: String,  lastname: String)
        val df = Seq (
         (1,"team1", 3, "Jonh", "Doe"),
         (1,"team2", 4, "Jonh", "Doe"),
         (1,"team3", 5, "David", "Luis"),
         (2,"team4", 6, "Michael", "Larson"))
         .toDF("id", "team", "members", "name",  "lastname").as[Zone]

val df_grouped = df
   .withColumn("team_info", to_json(struct(col("team"), col("members"))))
   .withColumn("users", to_json(struct(col("name"), col("lastname"))))
   .groupBy("id")
   .agg(collect_list($"team_info").alias("team_info"), collect_list($"users").alias("users"))

df_grouped.show    
    +---+--------------------+--------------------+
    | id|           team_info|               users|
    +---+--------------------+--------------------+
    |  1|[{"team":"team1",...|[{"name":"Jonh","...|
    |  2|[{"team":"team4",...|[{"name":"Michael...|
    +---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I need to remove duplicates inside column "users" because in my case if the json inside the array are exactly the same are duplicates. Is there any way to do it changing the value of that column with df.withColumn or any other approach?

Comment: provide your piece of code you tried

Comment: sorry, I will add the code.

Comment: I already figured out how to solve it. Using collect_set instead of collect_list

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not the most elegant solution, but it should work:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

val df = sc.parallelize(
  Array("[{\"name\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Doe\"},{\"name\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Doe\"},{\"name\":\"David\",\"lastName\":\"Luis\"}]")
).toDF("users")

case class Users(name: String, lastName: String)
val schema = ArrayType(Encoders.product[Users].schema)

df.withColumn("u", from_json($"users", schema))
  .select("u")
  .as[Array[Users]]
  .map(_.distinct)
  .toDF("u")
  .withColumn("users", to_json($"u"))
  .select("users")
```

Assuming your users will have more attributes than in your example, just add those attributes to the case class. As long as the types are simple, the `Encoder` should infer the schema automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **explode** and **dropDuplicates** inbuild functions

[spark dropDuplicates based on json array field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44505772/7130689)