# Pyspark: Two Rows With Same Value in Identifying Column ... Only Want to Keep One of Rows

Tags: python, filter, pyspark, duplicates

I have the following sample data set.

```
ID      Date
213412  2008-10-26T06:04:00.000Z
213412  2018-10-26T05:42:00.000Z
393859  2018-10-26T09:17:00.000Z
```

I have two ID values that are the same above.  I only want to keep one of the two rows for ID 213412 .... it doesn't matter to me which row I keep.

I know how to do the above in Pandas Python but have no idea how to do this in PySpark.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates from rows based on specific columns in an RDD/Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248221/removing-duplicates-from-rows-based-on-specific-columns-in-an-rdd-spark-datafram)

Comment: You can also use `df.groupBy("ID").select(*[first(c) for c in df.columns if c != "ID"])` where `first` is `pyspark.sql.functions.first`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **dropDuplicates()**

## Sample Data in DataFrame

```
>>> cols = ['ID', 'Date']

>>> vals =  [
        ('213412', '2008-10-26T06:04:00.000Z'),
        ('213412', '2008-10-26T06:04:00.000Z'),
        ('393859  ', '2018-10-26T09:17:00.000Z'),
        ]

# Create DataFrame
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, cols)
>>> df.show(3, False)

+--------+------------------------+
|ID      |Date                    |
+--------+------------------------+
|213412  |2008-10-26T06:04:00.000Z|
|213412  |2008-10-26T06:04:00.000Z|
|393859  |2018-10-26T09:17:00.000Z|
+--------+------------------------+
```

## Use dropDuplicates()

```
# You can simply use df.dropDuplicates(), but by specifying the Column (ID) you are telling Spark to drop based on that column.

df_dist = df.dropDuplicates(["ID"])
df_dist.show(2, False)

+--------+------------------------+
|ID      |Date                    |
+--------+------------------------+
|213412  |2008-10-26T06:04:00.000Z|
|393859  |2018-10-26T09:17:00.000Z|
+--------+------------------------+
```

For more information, refer

- **dropDuplicates()**:
  http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates