# elminate duplicates in a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Can I eliminate multiple values i Column_3,Column_4

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|Column_1|Column_2|Column_3|Column_4|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|       1|       x|     abc|     www|
|       1|       x|     abc|     sdf|
|       1|       x|     abc|     xyz|
|       1|       x|     def|     www|
|       1|       x|     def|     sdf|
|       1|       x|     def|     xyz|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Expected Output

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|Column_1|Column_2|Column_3|Column_4|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|       1|       x|     abc|     www|
|       1|       x|     def|     sdf|
|       1|       x|    null|     xyz|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Try `df.dropDuplicates(Array("Column_3"))`.

Comment: Hi @Uservxn - Welcome to SO :) couple of questions : 1. What is your spark version? 2. Is there any rule for keeping combination of `Column_3` and `Column_4` like how to decide that either keep ` abc |     www` or `abc|     sdf`.

Answer (score 0):

Use df.dropDuplicates(Column_3,Column_4)

Also, duplicate from [Removing duplicates from rows based on specific columns in an RDD/Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248221/removing-duplicates-from-rows-based-on-specific-columns-in-an-rdd-spark-datafram)

Comment: val df1 = Seq((1,"x","abc"),(1,"x","def")).toDF("Column_1","Column_2","Column_3")
> val df2 = Seq((1,"x","xyz"),(1,"x","www"),(1,"x","sdf")).toDF("Column_1","Column_2","Column_4")
> val df3 = df1.join(df2, Seq("Column_1","Column_2"), "outer")
> df3.show
--------+--------+
|Column_1|Column_2|Column_3|Column_4|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|       1|       x|     abc|     www|
|       1|       x|     abc|     sdf|
|       1|       x|     abc|     xyz|
|       1|       x|     def|     www|
|       1|       x|     def|     sdf|
|       1|       x|     def|     xyz|

Comment: df3.dropDuplicates("column_3","column_4")
res68: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [Column_1: int, Column_2: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> res68.show
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|Column_1|Column_2|Column_3|Column_4|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|       1|       x|     def|     xyz|
|       1|       x|     def|     sdf|
|       1|       x|     abc|     www|
|       1|       x|     def|     www|
|       1|       x|     abc|     sdf|
|       1|       x|     abc|     xyz|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+