# Pyspark dataframe: How to remove duplicate rows in a dataframe in databricks

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have an existing dataframe in databricks which contains many rows are exactly the same in all column values. example like below:

df:

| No. | Name | Age | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 20 | US |
| 1 | John | 20 | US |
| 2 | Cici | 25 | Japan |
| 3 | Tom | 36 | Canada |
| 3 | Tom | 36 | Canada |
| 3 | Tom | 36 | Canada |

I want to have the below finally.

| No. | Name | Age | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 20 | US |
| 2 | Cici | 25 | Japan |
| 3 | Tom | 36 | Canada |

How to write the scripts?
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates from rows based on specific columns in an RDD/Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248221/removing-duplicates-from-rows-based-on-specific-columns-in-an-rdd-spark-datafram)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use either `distinct` (or) `dropDuplicates()` functions on the dataframe.

**`Example:`**

```
df.distinct().show()
```

(or)

```
df.dropDuplicates().show()
```

---

**`Sample code:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'John',20,'US'),(1,'John',20,'US'),(1,'John',20,'US'),(2,'CICI',25,'Japan')],['No.','Name','Age','country'])
df.distinct().show()
df.dropDuplicates().show()
#output
#+---+----+---+-------+
#|No.|Name|Age|country|
#+---+----+---+-------+
#|  1|John| 20|     US|
#|  2|CICI| 25|  Japan|
#+---+----+---+-------+
#
#+---+----+---+-------+
#|No.|Name|Age|country|
#+---+----+---+-------+
#|  1|John| 20|     US|
#|  2|CICI| 25|  Japan|
#+---+----+---+-------+
```